# Where to save data cached in mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

Aim going to develop chat app which must has high security level
what you prefer to save old chat secure in the device ?
use local storage with encoding ?
or using cache in the same app ??
pros of using cache is handling for time period to delete old cache
pros of local storage that I can use more security libraries

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used Hive at least and secured data on it by encrypt it